# How to compile multiple jars that uses same application file with different controllers

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build

I am writing a `weather` service with 2 providers `weather-1` and `weather-2`. I have two `Spring Controller` classes `controller-1` and `controller-2` that call both the services respectively.

My intention is to switch between the two weather service jars, like if I want to get weather data from `weather-1` then `controller-1` has to compile with the `weather-1.jar` file while `controller-2` remains untouched.

I have tried with two different `Gradle` files for both the services like `build-weather-1.gradle` and `build-weather-2.gradle`.

Both will have the `jar` dependencies of their own.

**build-weather-1.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.xxx.weather:weather-1:0.0.1'
```

**build-weather-2.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.xxx.weather:weather-2:0.0.1'
```

I ran the `build-weather-1.gradle` with the command - `gradle -b build-weather-1.gradle build`. Unfortunately, this build file expects the other service class controller as well.

```
error: package com.xxx.weather.weather-2 does not exist
```

I have excluded the package as below,

```
sourceSets {
 main {
 java {
 exclude 'com/xxxx/weatherservice/controller/Weather2Controller.java'
 }
    }
}
```

But this interface(`weather-2`) is declared as a bean in the Application.java file which throws package not found error.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: I'm not very sure why you want to keep two different service controllers in same project. However did you try creating two different modules under a parent project and placing the controllers in their respective modules with their corresponding build files?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the following pattern:

1. Define a common `WeatherService` interface.
2. Both weather service implement this interface.
3. Implement a single controller, inject an implementation of the `WeatherService`  via it's constructor.

This is an example where the dependency-inversion principle applies, from the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID):

> High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions (e.g., interfaces).  Abstractions should not depend on details. Details (concrete implementations) should depend on abstractions.

In your application, the controller (implementation) depends on the `WeatherService` interface (abstraction), rather than the specific weather service implementations.

Once you've done the above, there are many options for deploying controllers that make use of the desired weather service implementation.  These include:

- In your `main()` method or using your chosen dependency-injection approach: construct an instance of the desired weather service implementation, and construct your controller using that instance.
- Make each weather service implementation a plugin, using something like [PF4J](https://github.com/pf4j/pf4j)
- Use reflection to find and construct whichever weather service implementation has been placed on the runtime classpath (assuming you compile each weather service implementation as a separate JAR, in addition to a core JAR containing the `WeatherService` interface and the controller).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if your projects need to be built independently from each other you should keep them as separate projects (In this case you could still share some code via a third library project which your other projects could depend on).

If you still want to keep them inside the same gradle structure you should look into a multi-module set up like mentioned in this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) and keep a build configuration for each sub module in its own build.gradle file.